If $f$ is a homeomorphism of class $C^r$ and $ \forall x$ , $f'(x)≠0$ then $f$ is $C^r -$diffeomorphism.
I found the following problem in Pugh's Analysis book:

If $f:(a,b) \rightarrow (c,d)$ is a homeomorphism of class $C^r$ where $1\leq r < \infty$ and $ \forall x\in (a,b)$
we've $f'(x)≠0$ then $f$ is a $C^r$ diffeomorphism.

My Attempt: Clearly it suffices to prove that $f^{-1}$ is a function of class $C^r .(r\geq1)$
Very naturally I'm trying to do it using induction.
For $r=1$ , we can write by Inverse Function Theorem $(f^{-1})'(y)=\frac{1}{f' (f^{-1}(y))}$ and hence $f',f^{-1}$ both are continuous (due to the hypothesis) & we're done.
But for $r\geq2$ , I'm confused a bit regarding the inductive step.
For $r=2$ , it's something like $(f^{-1})''(y)$ = $((f^{-1})'(y))' = (\frac{1}{f' (f^{-1}(y))})'$ but then how to proceed further? And how to proceed inductively for any $r\in \mathbb{N}$.
Maybe it's easy but I really can't get it rightly. If someone can write down the inductive step it'll be helpful for me.
Thanks in advance.

Is this what you are looking for? On derivatives of the inverse of a real function

@MartinR Yes, it's somewhat similar but Is there any easier way to do it? I mean without using that Faà di Bruno's formula , because I'm not very well aware of that formula.
